# Access-Control-Allow-Origin while header is given to API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I am facing problems with CORS headers while using React and Express. The error says the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing, but I've updated the API so it has the header, what to do?

This is the error I get:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/recipes' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

This is what my code looks like:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import db from './app/models/index.js'
// const db = require("./app/models");
// const Recipe = require("./app/models/recipe.model.js")

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081",
  
};

app.options(cors(corsOptions))

// app.use(cors(corsOptions)); 

db.sequelize.sync();

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept");
  if (req.accepts("json" || "xml" || "x-www-form-urlencoded")) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(406);
  }
});

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to Janessa's application." });
});

// require("./app/routes/recipe.routes")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: Please update the question with exact error messages too

Comment: I found that sometimes the "old" server keeps running for a while (a few minutes? until next system start ?). If you want to be sure your changes take effect, change the server port (8000 in your example) on every server start, until you are sure the old server process is gone. You do not need `cors` and the `res.header("Access-Control-Allow...` lines. One or the other should be sufficient.

Comment: @kca I tried it, but still get the same error. I also deleted the `app.use(function(req, res, next) { res.header(...;` lines

Comment: hmm, can be so many things, .. any script blockers active ? Pay attention if it is _exactly_ the same message, or a slightly different one. Also try a very simple server with e.g. `res.end({test: 'test'}) or something. It might say "cors error..." if it is actually some other error. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed)